# Include FactoryGirl Factories

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, mocking, factory-bot

I am using Factory Girl instead of fixtures.  I have noticed, that for my FactoryGirl classes to be available I have to call this code

```
def setup
   super
   Factory( :li_store);
   Factory( :li_customer);
   ....
```

If I don't have those lines in my setup or anywhere else in my test then my FactoryGirl objects aren't created.  Is there a way I can include my factories ?  I have tried adding a require statement of the factory file to the top of my test, but it complains that the objects are already registered.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tests `require 'factory_girl'` and put your `factories.rb` file under `/specs` or `/tests`.

The `factories.rb` file looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :li_store do
    this "dewdew"
    that "rrfr"
  end
end
```

In your tests you then just call

```
var = Factory :li_store
```

Comment: So there isn't a way for me to tell it to "create all the objects listed in this factory" without calling "Factory :blah" for each and every object listed in my SomethingFactory.rb ?

Comment: maybe you misunderstood the concept of FG? You create new objects through FG whenever you need one. They are predictable and can be changed or in sequences if needed. That's the advantage over fixtures as you probably know them. You can however mass create objects. I forgot the syntax though. It's in the getting_started.md file in the FG repo.

Comment: Now that you mention it I think you are right.  I was thinking of them as seeding a db to make it suitable for a test.  Thanks for the help and correcting my erroneous thought process.

Comment: FG as it is is a lot more powerful than static data and a lot more useful in that way. You introduce your objects right where you need them the way you want. It is a bit difficult to get there though. Took me some time too :)

Comment: btw, put away those `;`in your code. You're coding with Ruby.